# Query timeout expired with only one parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, oledb

I have been facing a peculiar issue of Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

> Error '80040e31' Query timeout expired while executing below query.

This query throws this error only if parameter `tblIndentrecords.AccepterID = 641`, whereas for values 621, 681 etc (these are user ids) it runs smoothly.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(tblindentitems.QUANTITY) AS IndentQty, 
    tblIndentRecords.INDENTNO, tblIndentRecords.PROJECTNO, 
    tblIndentRecords.TYPE, tblIndentRecords.RevNo,
    tblIndentRecords.INDENTDATE, tblIndentRecords.Amdtdate, 
    tblIndentRecords.ITEM,
    tblIndentRecords.CreaterID, tblIndentRecords.CreaterINL, tblIndentRecords.CREATEDBY,
    tblIndentRecords.ApproverID, tblIndentRecords.ApproverINL, tblIndentRecords.APPROVEDBY,
    tblIndentRecords.APPROVALDATE, 
    tblIndentRecords.Status, tblIndentRecords.PurchaseStatus,
    tblIndentRecords.AccepterID, tblIndentRecords.AccepterINL, tblIndentRecords.AcceptedBy,
    tblIndentRecords.AccDate, 
    tblIndentRecords.CriticalItem, 
    SUM(tblPOItems.Quantity) AS POQty 
FROM 
    tblindentitems 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblIndentRecords ON tblindentitems.CoID = tblIndentRecords.CoID 
                     AND tblindentitems.SubID = tblIndentRecords.SubID 
                     AND tblindentitems.PROJECTNO = tblIndentRecords.PROJECTNO 
                     AND tblindentitems.INDENTNO = tblIndentRecords.INDENTNO 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblPOItems ON tblindentitems.PROJECTNO = tblPOItems.ProjectNo 
               AND tblindentitems.INDENTNO = tblPOItems.IndentNo 
WHERE 
    (tblindentitems.CoID = 3) 
    AND (tblIndentrecords.AccepterID = 641) 
    AND (tblindentItems.IndentNo > 0) 
    AND (tblIndentrecords.status = 1) 
    AND (tblIndentrecords.Purchasestatus = 1) 
    AND (tblIndentrecords.IndentDate > '4/28/2019') 
GROUP BY 
    tblIndentRecords.INDENTNO, tblIndentRecords.PROJECTNO, tblIndentRecords.INDENTNO,
    tblIndentRecords.TYPE, tblIndentRecords.RevNo, tblIndentRecords.INDENTDATE,
    tblIndentRecords.Amdtdate, tblIndentRecords.ITEM, tblIndentRecords.VENDOR,
    tblIndentRecords.RequiredBy, tblIndentRecords.CreaterID, tblIndentRecords.CreaterINL, 
    tblIndentRecords.CREATEDBY, tblIndentRecords.ApproverID, tblIndentRecords.ApproverINL, 
    tblIndentRecords.APPROVEDBY, tblIndentRecords.APPROVALDATE, tblIndentRecords.COMMENTS, 
    tblIndentRecords.Status, tblIndentRecords.PurchaseStatus, tblIndentRecords.AccepterID, 
    tblIndentRecords.AccepterINL, tblIndentRecords.AcceptedBy, tblIndentRecords.AccDate, 
    tblIndentRecords.Mode, tblIndentRecords.BOQDATE, tblIndentRecords.BOQREF, 
    tblIndentRecords.BOQREV, tblIndentRecords.Orderid, tblIndentRecords.CriticalItem, 
    tblIndentRecords.DespatchClosed, tblIndentRecords.BasicAmount, tblIndentRecords.NetAmount, 
    tblIndentRecords.PrintOption 
HAVING 
    ((SUM(tblindentitems.QUANTITY) - SUM(tblPOItems.Quantity)) > 0 OR SUM(tblPOItems.Quantity) IS NULL) 
ORDER BY 
    tblIndentRecords.Item, tblIndentRecords.ProjectNo, tblIndentRecords.INDENTNO DESC
```

Comment: Well, then you need to debug and find out why a value of **641** causes the error, while others don't. Does **641** refer to a lot more details rows? Is there something else special or unique about that value? Since we don't have your whole project and data at hand, it's nearly impossible to offer more precise help....

Comment: Thanks a lot. Surprisingly 641 has least records.  There is nothing special or unique. These are user ids (id field) of a table. It is driving me insane.

Comment: OK, two more things: first - why are you using the "OleDB" provider? Can't you use the "SQL Native Client" ? What language/programming environment do you call this SQL from? Also: can you use SQL Server Profiler to see what the queries for **641** and for other values look like? Can you capture the actual execution plans - any differences there?